# AngularJS dropdown scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need some help. thanks for any answers!
I want to change this code..

```
<select id='input_location' name='input_location[]' multiple="multiple">
<option value=""></option>
    <?
    $car_locations = $this->item_model->getAllLocation();
         foreach($car_locations as $m){?>

    <option value='<?=$m->office_city_state?>'> <?=($m->office_city_state)?> </option>
    <?}?>
    </select>
```

to this code.

```
<span ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example1data" selected-model="example1model"> </span>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $("#input_location").multiSelect();

        var jayApp = angular.module('jayApp',['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);
        jayApp.controller('jayController', function($scope) {
                               $scope.example1model = []; 
                               $scope.example1data = [ {id: 1, label: "David"}, {id: 2, label: "Jhon"}, {id: 3, label: "Danny"}];
                                    })

 </script>
```

How can I use foreach code to $scope.example1data ??

Comment: http://myforce.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/

Comment: I read it already but i'm not sure what to do.. sorry for asking stupidly

Comment: that's OK. Are you using angularjs for the entire app or just this part ?

Comment: only this part!